# Incomplete type not allowed when using new[] keyword

Tags: c++

This code gives errors

> incomplete type is not allowed
>
> too many initializer values

```cpp
string *ReturnTwoStringsInArray()
{
   return new string[]{"return1", "return2"};
}
```

This one works:

```cpp
string *ReturnTwoStringsInArray()
{
   return new string[2]{"return1", "return2"};
}
```

And so does this one:

```cpp
string arr[]{"return1","return"};
```

Shouldn't we be able to call `new` with no parameters in `[]` if the compiler can determine the needed size from the initializer list?

Comment: First version is a nrw expression to create zero-sized array, which is not correct. Third is declaration and initialization, where it's perfectly legal as it was defined behaviour for array declaratiom. 2nd is a new expression which got own rules...

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie The first is a [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) expression with unknown bound and the bound is supposed to be deduced, like in this example: `double* p = new double[]{1,2,3};` from cppreference. Looks like a compiler bug. It seems to work in clang but not gcc or msvc: https://godbolt.org/z/CQG-vq

Comment: Can you return `std::array<std::string,2>` instead?

Comment: Yeah i could , but currently i'm just experimenting with this but can't seem to find an answer why isn't this allowed on all compilers . And I did include <string> and have tried it with <cstring> also

Comment: @TedLyngmo that's what happens with after-fact changes.. production doesn't tolerate well retcon in rules. To be honest I don't know any widely-used in production compilers that ever patched selves to accommodate changes in versions already issued and embedded into stable. It breaks life cycle. clang is exception because of its platform's requirements.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Most of the widely used compilers have made changes to fix defect reports in earlier C++ versions if I read the table correctly. If such a change doesn't risk breaking existing code (like P1009R2) I see no harm. If one upgrades to a newer version of the compiler, one gets access to the new functionality. I guess reading the release notes before upgrading the compiler for a system already in production is key. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah, that seems main reason , to be afraid of breaking code and need to vet whole code base again because compiler was changed (that's security measures, in case of OSS that means whole OS should be vetted again). ALso sometimes _allowing_ new functionality breaks code, especially large template-ECS systems because it may break SFINAE: expression that was illegal suddenly becomes legal, etc.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I'm not aware of any fixes for defect reports that have had that effect on earlier C++ versions. What you describe could be said for any upgrade in the toolchain one may want to consider. It has to be done with care and even if upgrading the compiler is usually rather painless, it's just software and will probably have new bugs in place of the old fixed ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [C++ compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) we can see that the defect report `P1009R2`:[Array size deduction in new-expressions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1009r2.pdf) has not been adopted by all compiler vendors yet.

`P1009R2` says: "*The effect of the wording changes should be applied in implementations of all previous versions of C++ where they apply.*"

`clang++` supports it from version 9 in C++11 mode and later.